# Java input validation for multiple entries on the same line with Scanner

Tags: java, validation

I'm using the Scanner to get an integer input from a user. In this case the integer should be between 5 and 10 inclusive.

I have this working with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class valin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int inputNumber;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 5 and 10: ");

            while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again: ");
                in.next();
            }

            inputNumber = in.nextInt();

            if (inputNumber < 5 || inputNumber > 10) {
                System.out.println("Needs to be a number between 5 and 10. Try again.");
            }

        } while (inputNumber < 5 || inputNumber > 10);

        System.out.println("You entered: " + inputNumber);
        in.close();

    }

}
```

The problem I have is when the user inputs more than 1 input on a line. In this case my code will display as:

```
Enter a number between 5 and 10: 
www eee
That is not a number. Please try again: 
That is not a number. Please try again: 
qqq 6
That is not a number. Please try again: 
You entered: 6
```

What I want is if the user enters for example "qqq 6" or any "input whitespace input" that the code will tell the user it is invalid and to enter it again.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes you can by adding ckeck_method to control your input as an array

Comment: If an user inputs more values with space is a valid input or not? ex `5 6` ?

Comment: An other idea: you can read the whole line as a `String` and try to convert it into an `int`. If it's not possible to convert you will receive a `NumberFormatException` and you can tell this bad news to your user. Moreover, I'm not sure but event if the user enters a multi-line string you can try to iterate over the input lines and append all this to one single `String` that you can try to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version catching NumberFormatException, as suggested by a few other people:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class valin {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Integer inputNumber = -1;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 5 and 10: ");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
      String line = in.nextLine().trim();

      try{
        inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);
      }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("That is not a number. Please try again.");
        continue;
      }

      if(inputNumber >= 5 && inputNumber <= 10){
        System.out.println("You entered: " + inputNumber);
        break;
      }else{
        System.out.println("That is not a number between 5 and 10. Please try again.");
      }
    }

    in.close();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your "in" var in a string [] variable, then check for each element if it is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to do it using regular expressions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class valin {

  private static final Pattern INT_5_TO_10 = Pattern.compile("[5-9]|10");

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int inputNumber;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 5 and 10: ");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
      String line = in.nextLine().trim();
      Matcher m = INT_5_TO_10.matcher(line);

      if(m.matches()){
        inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);   //Only neccessary if you want to use this later on, otherwise we don't need to parse the number
        System.out.println("You entered: " + inputNumber);
        break;
      }else{
        System.out.println("That is not a number between 5 and 10. Please try again.");
      }
    }

    in.close();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in the line

```
inputNumber = in.nextInt();
```

The entered input with white space will be readed and parsed twice.
So you can use

```
String input = in.nextLine();
```

to take the input from the user and then parse this string input to Integer using

```
inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

So that you can overcome by above mentioned problem.

The code `Integer.parseInt(input)` may results in NumberFormatException. Please handle the necessary exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is "tighter" version of the solution provided by @James Baker that uses capturing group in the regular expression and try with resources

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static final Pattern INT_5_TO_10 = Pattern.compile("([5-9]|10)");

    private static int parse(String line) {
        Matcher m = INT_5_TO_10.matcher(line.trim());
        return m.matches() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) : -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inputNumber;
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 5 and 10: ");

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                inputNumber = parse(line);

                if (inputNumber > 0) {
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + inputNumber);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("That is not a number between 5 and 10. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```